# Running a linux subprocess in python with sudo

Tags: python, django, subprocess, popen

So, this is kind of confusing but essentially I'm using Django and I want to instantiate a subprocess to run a perl script. I've read that this can be done with

```
arg = "/some/file/path/"
pipe = subprocess.Popen(["./uireplace", arg], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

which works when I call it in the appropriate function in views.py but the script requires a sudo. I then call this

```
pipe = subprocess.Popen(["sudo","./uireplace", arg], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

which works when I run it in python from a terminal but this doesn't work when it's called by a random user on the web. Is there any way to be able to automatically enter in a username and password for that sudo? The issue is that this can't be done with a prompt so it simply fails.

Comment: Either fix the correct permissions for the script called/calling, or let the calling script/user use [sudo without password](http://askubuntu.com/questions/39281/how-to-run-an-application-using-sudo-without-a-password).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solves this problem on the OS level. Giving any user from the web the right to use `sudo` does not sound right. Just make `./uireplace` executable.  There are lots of options  for [chmod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) to fine tune this.